# Calling a function in onPostExecute() method

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView and it has 100 rows based on items. And here is loading spinner, it will spin untill ListView is loaded, so `listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and `progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);` is in onPostexecute method, and i placed a `TakeScreenShot();` method there, so when listView loading completed, i want to take a screenshot.

**Problem is that** after listview complete its loading, it takes 100 screenshots. and i want to take only one.

here is code:

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        TakeScreenShot();
        Log.i("TakeScreenShot", "--> Done......");

        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.requestLayout();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {


        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please paste the code where you are executing this async task

Comment: @ThomasMary please check the edited question

Comment: In my opinion, it takes 100 screenshots because you have 100 AsyncTask running, but your code is not that clear

Comment: i'm getting facebook user posts ids and i set limit=100 in facebook api, and you're right every post id get = 1 Asynctask running

Comment: 100 post ids = 100 tasks, what i should do?

Comment: Could you please reformat your code! It is hard to read.

Comment: @Barns Please check the edited question with more info.

Comment: First of all "Task().execute();" is being called from within the `for` loop and it will be called "jsonArray.length()"  times. Since "TakeScreenShot" is in that task you will take "jsonArray.length()" screenshots. Now for a little critique on your code--not very efficient: you are adding `HashMap` to the "contactList" `ArrayList`, then your are iterating through the entire list EACH LOOP!! to remove "id" that may already exist? WOW!

Comment: This code remove duplicate id's from the arraylist and show every single I'd in listview... Everything is fine but bit confused where to execute task async to wait for list load @Barns

Comment: Glad I could help with your problem of calling "Task" from with in the `for` loop. Now to your iterating through the loop in order to remove the duplicate "id" from your list. It is best not to add them at all. Consider using a `HashMap<String, String> listMap` before you add a new value to the `Map` check `if(!listMap.containsKey(key))` as a condition before you add the value.

Comment: your full suggestion code may help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by executing Task Async outside from loop.